# Ntoskrnl.exe in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit , and I was surprised to find that Ntoskrnl.exe under C:\WINDOWS\System32 is a 32-bit executable ...
Can you please explain why ?

Comment: What's would you expect it to be?

Comment: a 64-bit executable as the kernel runs in a 64-bit arch

Comment: On System32 folder though, not on SysWOW64.

Comment: For ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457298/why-is-the-ntoskrnl-exe-image-machinetype-header-field-set-to-x86-on-only-certai

Comment: Found this : http://www.osronline.com/ShowThread.cfm?link=218039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what application you use to browse to system32 :) Windows uses a virtualized environment to make 32-bit applications believe they are running in 32-bit (which is necessary for them to run at all).

So if you're looking at system32 from a 32-bit application, all the dlls and everything are 32-bit :) Instead, look into `C:\Windows\sysnative`.